# What kind of algorithm would work here?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I need to write a pancake algorithm that works something like this. Say the waiter serves pancakes with either the  "+" side up or "-" side up. So a bunch of pancakes would look something like this: "--+-". My goal is to have all the pancakes with "+" side up. But the catch here is that I can only flip them from the top (the left side of the string) and can only flip batches. So a valid move to switch "--+-" would be to:

1. Flip the entire batch. ("+-++")
2. Then flip the top one to get("--++")
3. Then flip the top two to get ("++++")

I have to achieve this in the least amount of moves possible. I have tried looking online but have come up with algorithms for numbers which rely on their different magnitudes. Just need some sort of idea as to how to approach this problem.
Also, I'm coding this in Python which I am new to. So any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: this is a recursion problem.  check out towers of hanoi

Comment: Bill Gates to the rescue https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting

Comment: Take a look at http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pancake-sorting/

Comment: Also the [content analysis of this problem on Google Code Jam](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/6254486/dashboard#s=a&a=1).

Comment: I'll check these out!